# Switching between tabs with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, tabs, puppeteer

I need a example how to switch betweens tabs with puppeteer

this is currently what i have:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');



(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, // launch headful mode
});


    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
                await page.goto('https://URL1.com');




    const pagee = await browser.newPage();
    await pagee.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
                await pagee.goto('https://URL2.com');

})();
```

So it opens 2 tabs first:Url1, second: Url2

What i need:

first Tab do some action...
go to second Tab do some action...
go back to first Tab do some action...

can you guys please provide me a example ?

thank you

Answer (score 17):

The bit of code you need is `page.bringToFront` [See here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagebringtofront)

A working script below. Please note I have adding in a `wait` between tab switching else the script runs to fast :)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {
        headless: false
    }); 

    const page1 = await browser.newPage(); 
    await page1.goto('https://www.google.com');

    const page2 = await browser.newPage(); 
    await page2.goto('https://www.bing.com');

    const pageList = await browser.pages();    
    console.log("NUMBER TABS:", pageList.length);

    //switch tabs here
    await page1.bringToFront();
    blockingWait(1);
    await page2.bringToFront();
    blockingWait(1);
    await page1.bringToFront();
    blockingWait(4);

    await browser.close(); 
}; 

function blockingWait(seconds) {
    //simple blocking technique (wait...)
    var waitTill = new Date(new Date().getTime() + seconds * 1000);
    while(waitTill > new Date()){}

}

run();
```

Comment: FWIW, the `blockingWait` implementation is very wasteful, it's better to wait passively instead, e.g. `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, seconds * 1000))`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of clicking on a link/button to open a new tab with a new URL, the following worked for me.

```
await page.click('#your_Button_To_Open_New_Tab_With_Different_URL')
await page.waitForTimeout(3000)
const pageList = await browser.pages();    
await console.log("NUMBER TABS:", pageList.length);
await console.log("NUMBER TABS:", pageList[2]._target._targetInfo.url);
await page.waitForTimeout(3000)
page2 = await browser.newPage()
            
const redirectedUrlforService =   pageList[2]._target._targetInfo.url;
await page2.goto(redirectedUrlforService)
await page2.bringToFront(); 
              
await page2.waitForTimeout(3000)
await page2.waitForSelector('#A_Selector_On_New_Page_To_Verify_That_You_Can_Perform_Your_Actions_There')
```

Waiting for idle network requests might not always work if the responses involve long-running DOM updates that take longer than 500ms to trigger a render.